# Converting (Dictionary<string, List<string>>) value).Values)which is a collection to array by IValueConverter to show in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

my converter is as follows-

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var fields = (((Dictionary<string, List<string>>) value).Values);

        string dogCsv = string.Join("", (object[]) fields.ToArray());
        string dogCsv1 = string.Join("", dogCsv.ToArray());
        Array ab = dogCsv1.ToArray();
        return ab;
    }
```

my WPF binding is as follows-

```
<ListBox x:Name="txt"  FontSize="20" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Obj.StudDetail,ElementName=window, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  Background="Gray"/>
                <ListBox   Height="Auto" FontSize="20" MinHeight="100"
                           MinWidth="100" Width="Auto"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Obj.StudDetail, 


ElementName=window, Converter={StaticResource Converter1}}"
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         </ListBox>
```

i have used datatemplate to customize UI.
i want the output to be the value of my dictionary. PLease help. Thanks in advance.

Below is my C# code-
XAML.CS-

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Person Obj { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Obj = new Person();

        List<string> subjects1 = new List<string>();

        subjects1.Add("C++");
        subjects1.Add("C");
        subjects1.Add("C#");

        List<string> subjects2 = new List<string>();

        subjects2.Add("JAVA");
        subjects2.Add("JS");
        subjects2.Add("CSS");

        Obj.StudDetail.Add("Kushagra", subjects1);
        Obj.StudDetail.Add("Yash", subjects2);

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public class Person
    {
        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _studDetail = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> StudDetail
        {
            get { return _studDetail; }
            set { _studDetail = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

}
i also have one more converter class which returns the collection of keys. It is named as ValueConverter.

Comment: Why is there a ListBox in the DataTemplate of a ListBox, both with the same ItemsSource Binding? That makes no sense at all. Please clean up this mess. And instead of showing us just your code, please explain what you are trying to achieve. What data does the Dictionary hold, and how is it supposed to be displayed? "*output to be the value of my dictionary*" is not precise enough.

Comment: @Clemens i am trying to get keys of the dictionary as the heading of list box and the values of the dictionary as the content of particular list box that's the reason of two list box and sorry for my mistake if any i am fairly new to wpf

Comment: Can you please add the view model code for Obj.StudDetail? From the first look, your template seems not correct, ListBox.ItemTemplate is for items in the list not for the list

Comment: @ToanNguyen yes i have updated it now.

Comment: @Clemens i want the output in a stack like Key as heading/Label/1st element then  the Value which is in form of list then next Key and under that it's value so that I don't have to change the UI if I have to add more values in dictionary. Hope this could explain my query. PS- I am very bad at explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you do not actually need to use a value converter (as shown in the other answer), it may just look like shown below - with whatever separator strings you may want to use instead of blanks.

Note that the converter does not convert the whole Dictionary, but only its individual `KeyValuePair` entries, which are passed by `{Binding Converter={StaticResource Converter}` in the ListBox's ItemTemplate.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var result = "";

    if (value is KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>)
    {
        var kvp = (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>)value;

        result = kvp.Key + " " + string.Join(" ", kvp.Value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Your XAML would simply be this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Obj.StudDetail, ElementName=window}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

Alternatively, bind the `Key` and `Value` properties separately, the latter Binding with a converter that converts from `List<string>` to string:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var values = value as IEnumerable<string>;

    return values != null ? string.Join(" ", values) : "";
}
```

With this ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Or this one:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: sry but this code isn't working as expected. I am getting a blank white screen by this.

Comment: Certainly because `ElementName=window` was missing in the ItemsSource Binding. See the edited answer.

Comment: yes that seemed to be the problem now it worked just fine. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't knew that you could only accept 1 answer I clicked both and it unregistered yours.

Comment: the second edit is not working it seem to break because of run time error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

Comment: @kushagrabisht That's why there is `Mode=OneWay`. Instead of two Runs in a TextBlock, you may as well use two TextBlocks in a horizontal StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the converter and you can show the data like this

```
<ListBox x:Name="txt"  FontSize="20" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Obj.StudDetail,ElementName=window}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"  Background="Gray"/>
                        <ListBox   Height="Auto" FontSize="20" MinHeight="100"
                                   MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}"
                                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

What I did here is binding TextBlock to Key and the nested listbox to Value

Comment: But just out of curiosity is there a way to make it work with use of converter.

Comment: @kushagrabisht See my answer.

Comment: As a note, the nested ListBox here should better be an ItemsControl. Otherwise you would have to deal with selection inside the item container of an outer control with selection.